# Poor performance on IIS 7.5 nuget server

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, nuget-server

I have a locally-hosted nuget server on IIS 7.5. It seems that, as more packages are added to the site's feed, performance gets progressively worse. IIS is frequently scanning the contents of the Package folder, which is causing publishing to the site and requests to retrieve packages to time out.

Is this an IIS thing, where IIS wants to scan the contents of the packages every time there's a change?

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 0):

The simple NuGet.Server package was not designed for anything but a handful of packages. It uses an in-memory hashtable, and watches the file system for changes. If you have any other usage beyond trivial, you need to get a real private server. These private repositories also have the benefit of being easier to set-up and maintain.

Inedo's [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) is by far the most popular choice for on-prem NuGet servers, but both [JFrog](http://www.jfrog.com/) and [Sonatype](http://sonatype.com/) have options as well.

[MyGet](http://myget.org/) is by far the most popular choice for a cloud-hosted NuGet servers, but there may be others.

You could also try to spin-up an instance of NuGet.org, but that was never designed for use as a private package repository... just *the* public NuGet.org for private packages.